# Changes made in java resource files not reflected in war deployment

Tags: java, maven, gwt, jboss, war

I have a web application, and I'm trying to fix a bug in the code but no matter what I do in the .java files within my java resource folder when I deploy my war file the changes aren't reflected.

I've commented out event handlers, changed the text within buttons, and written print statements but regardless of the changes I make when I deploy my WAR file on the Jboss server it doesn't reflect. The changes I make to the .java files are going into the WAR file I've opened up the compiled .class file within the war and it reflects the changes I've made in my code. However once the web app is deployed the changes that are present in the .class files aren't reflected.

Side note If I modify the JSP files those changes do get reflected in the WAR, so I'm not sure where it's going wrong. The app uses GWT so I'm not sure if there's some issue or setting that makes my code used a previously cached JS files. If you need any more information please let me know and I'll try my best to provide.

My current deployment Process:

1. I run a maven clean/maven build to create my WAR file
2. I copy the WAR file within target directory and paste it into my Jboss server deployments folder
3. Jboss instantly recognizes a file is there and starts to deploy application
4. Same web application regardless of the change

**I'm fairly certain the issue has to do with GWT because that the JS is the only thing that doesn't change**

================================
UPDATE
=================================
I've managed to compile my java files into GWT JS files and added that to my WAR file. However my application is still showing the old names for buttons that I've since modified. I'm at a loss as to what could be the issue now.

Comment: What version of JBoss EAP or WildFly are you using?

Comment: I'm using Jboss 7.1 and Jboss is also using WildyFly core 3.0.10.Final-redhat

Comment: What do your logs look like? You should see information on the context name that was deployed. You'll want to make sure it's the same.

Comment: It's deploying the correctly named content folder. I'm 80% sure the issue lies in my webContent folder (folder used to generate WAR file) not getting an updated version of the GWT compiled Java code. As I inherited this project from someone else I was never given actual instructions on how to edit this application properly.

Comment: Ah, okay. That sounds like a build issue then.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete what is inside tmp and data/content and try again.

Comment: Whenever I remove an old WAR file and redeploy a new one it creates new data/content/* folder for the new WAR, I've also deleted the directory manually, this didn't fix the issue.